# Having Trouble figuring out the highest value through a for in loop

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble figuring out a way to loop the object in the objectMap to give me the Highest value of the fruits it gathered.My question is, how do I get loop to get the highest value using a `for in` loop. I have attached my code below.And where i have stopped,by the `for in` loop

```js
var fruitString = 'Banana,Banana,Pear,Orange,Apple,Melon,Grape,Apple,Banana,Grape,Melon,Grape,Melon,Apple,Grape,Banana,Orange,Melon,Orange,Banana,Banana,Orange,Pear,Grape,Orange,Orange,Apple,Apple,Banana'

  var fruitList = fruitString.split(',')
  var fruitMap = {};

  function soldfruits(){ 

    for (var i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
        var currentFruit = fruitList[i]
    if (fruitMap[currentFruit] === undefined) {// cehck if fruit is not available
         fruitMap[currentFruit]= 0;
        }
        fruitMap[currentFruit] = fruitMap[currentFruit] +1
    }
    console.log(fruitMap);
  }

  soldfruits(fruitMap); // calling function for check.

  for (var fruits in fruitMap) {
    if ( ) {

       }
  }
```

Comment: could you please re-check my answer as the answer? I edited the post to have it show the name of the item as well, and it lost the answer check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fruitString = 'Banana,Banana,Pear,Orange,Apple,Melon,Grape,Apple,Banana,Grape,Melon,Grape,Melon,Apple,Grape,Banana,Orange,Melon,Orange,Banana,Banana,Orange,Pear,Grape,Orange,Orange,Apple,Apple,Banana'

var fruitList = fruitString.split(',')
var fruitMap = {};

function soldfruits(){
for (var i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
    var currentFruit = fruitList[i]
if (fruitMap[currentFruit] === undefined) {
     fruitMap[currentFruit]= 0;
    }
    fruitMap[currentFruit] = fruitMap[currentFruit] +1
}
console.log(fruitMap);
return fruitMap
}


var fmap = soldfruits(fruitMap);

var high = 0
var high_name = ''
for(var x in fmap)
{
    if(fmap[x] > high)
    {
         high = fmap[x]
         high_name = x
    }
}
console.log(high + ' ' + high_name)
```

Comment: This does not tell you which one was the high

Comment: He only asked for the highest number, not the name. It would be easy to modify it to display the name as well if he needs to.

Comment: @raphael75 Can you just clarify to me what is happening here at the bottom by the for in loop.

Comment: @mplungjan, I just edited it to show the name of the highest item as well. :)

Comment: I saw it. You do not like semicolons much ;) (Yes I know they are not mandatory)

Comment: @DwayneSauls, I added "return fruitMap" to your loop at the top, which is then set to the variable "fmap". fmap holds your associative array. I then set a variable to hold the highest value and the name of the highest value. The for...in loop goes through each item in the associative array and checks to see if the current value is higher than the currently-highest value (stored in "high"), and sets it to be the new high value. In the for...in array, x holds the key (Banana, Pear, etc.).

Comment: @mplungjan, I just did it really fast & didn't include them. It still works :)

Comment: @DwayneSauls, it would be helpful for you to step through it in your browser's javascript inspector/tools (Firebug, etc.) to see exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and check, if `fruitList` has a value of the propery `fruit`. If not take zero otherwise the value of the propery and add one. Then assign to the property.

```js
var fruitString = 'Banana,Banana,Pear,Orange,Apple,Melon,Grape,Apple,Banana,Grape,Melon,Grape,Melon,Apple,Grape,Banana,Orange,Melon,Orange,Banana,Banana,Orange,Pear,Grape,Orange,Orange,Apple,Apple,Banana',
    fruitList = fruitString.split(','),
    fruitMap = {},
    highest = 0;

fruitList.forEach(function (fruit) {
    fruitMap[fruit] = (fruitMap[fruit] || 0) + 1;
    if (fruitMap[fruit] > highest) {
        highest = fruitMap[fruit];
    }
});

console.log(fruitMap);
console.log(highest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Which one is the highest??

Comment: He wants the number more than the fruit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var highest = {fruit:"", num:0}
for (var fruit in fruitMap) {
  var num = fruitMap[fruit];
  if (num > highest.num) { // if the current number of fruits is greater than the saved
    highest.fruit=fruit; // save the fruit
    highest.num=num;     // save the number
  }
}
console.log(highest);
```

Alternatively sort the array using object sort and pop the last

```js
var fruitString = 'Banana,Banana,Pear,Orange,Apple,Melon,Grape,Apple,Banana,Grape,Melon,Grape,Melon,Apple,Grape,Banana,Orange,Melon,Orange,Banana,Banana,Orange,Pear,Grape,Orange,Orange,Apple,Apple,Banana'

var fruitList = fruitString.split(',')
var fruitMap = {};

function soldfruits() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fruitList.length; i++) {
    var currentFruit = fruitList[i]
    if (fruitMap[currentFruit] === undefined) {
      fruitMap[currentFruit] = 0;
    }
    fruitMap[currentFruit] = fruitMap[currentFruit] + 1
  }
  console.log(fruitMap);
}


soldfruits(fruitMap);

var highest = {fruit:"", num:0}
for (var fruit in fruitMap) {
  var num = fruitMap[fruit];
  if (num > highest.num) {
    highest.fruit=fruit;
    highest.num=num;
  }
}
console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the highest number of fruit sold and also the names of those fruit.

```
var mostSold = 0;
var mostFruits = [];
for (var fruits in fruitMap) {
  if (fruitMap[fruits] > mostSold) {
    // store the number of fruit sold
    mostSold = fruitMap[fruits];
    // initialise the list with the fruit name
    mostFruits = [fruits];
  }
  else if (fruitMap[fruits] == mostSold) {
    // add the fruit name to the list
    mostFruits.push(fruits);
  }
}
console.log( mostSold + ' : ' + mostFruits );
```

Comment: Perhaps a snippet?